# Regex: Remove words or letters starting and ending with a character

Tags: r, regex

I want to remove words or letters starting and ending with specific characters in R using Regex.

For example,

```
"I want to delete @word&"
```

Should be

```
 "I want to delete"
```

And

```
"I  want to delete @p&"
```

Should be

```
"I want to delete"
```

Comment: why close or downvote ? this is a perfectly reasonable question

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gsub` :

```
gsub("@[^&]*&","","I want to delete @word&")
# [1] "I want to delete "


gsub("(^|\\s)@[^&]*&","","I  want to delete @p&")
# [1] "I  want to delete "
```

The way to handle the extra space would depend of your real case but I believe the following should be fine if a trimmed output is acceptable:

```
trimws(gsub("\\s*@[^&]*&","","@nope& hello @nope& world @nope&"))
# [1] "hello world"
```

Answer (score 0):

Different pattern - it just enough to make `+` non-greedy :

```
gsub("@.+?&","","I want to delete @word&")
```