# Replace each occurrence ending with a specific letter from a string separated by blanks

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

I would like to remove all occurrences which end with a specific letter (lets say "a") from a string. I am not dealing with a vector composed of different elements but rather a string separated by spaces.

Here are the data:

```
have = "Da 4e 5c 6a 7a"
want = "4e 5c"
```

Any idea?

Thank you in advance,

Anthony

Comment: Could you show a sample of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Duplicate to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51620752/regex-remove-words-or-letters-starting-and-ending-with-a-character) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22615188/remove-all-words-that-start-with-from-a-string)?

Comment: You can probably use [`\w+a ?`](https://regex101.com/r/IDMmds/1). One or more *word characters* followed by an `a`, followed by an optional space. Still you'd need to right trim spaces with this one.

Comment: Without trimming an idea to use [conditional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) (`perl=TRUE`) like this: [`( )?\w+a(?(1)| )`](https://regex101.com/r/IDMmds/2) or you can simply use alternation without magic: [`\w+a | \w+a`](https://regex101.com/r/IDMmds/3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using link from [@PoGibas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22615188/remove-all-words-that-start-with-from-a-string)

```
gsub("\\w+a *", "", have)
# "4e 5c "
```

Answer (score 3):

Not the best approach but you could try:

```
trimws(gsub("([A-Z]|[0-9])([a])","",have))
[1] "4e 5c"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a way with ws trimming on both sides

Find
`(?<!\S)(?:[^\S\r\n]*\S*a[^\S\r\n]*)+`

Replace
*`nothing`*

Rationale

```
 (?<! \S )              # Wsp boundary, this will leave 1 space behind for separation
 (?:                    # Group
      [^\S\r\n]*             # optional horizontal whitespaces
      \S*                    # optional non-whitespaces
      a                      # required, ends with an  'a'
      [^\S\r\n]*             # optional horizontal whitespaces
 )+                     # End group, do 1 to many sequences
```